# How to add leading zero to different char length in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi,I have one query for different tables and all of them have different length which requires leading zero for the `ID`. Is it possible to use one query that will add leading zero to any table?

lets say first query is `insert to tbl1_field1(CHAR 3) 001`, then next query is `insert to tbl2_field2(CHAR 4) 0001` then next is `insert to tlb3_field3(CHAR 10) 0000000001`. I am using `php and mysql`

Comment: Why do you need leading zeroes in the ID... store as a straight number, and format on output to display with leading zeroes

Comment: @MarkBaker, you totally beat me to it... I hate asking questions in response to questions but this one is unavoidable. Cindy, if you have leading 0z in your "ID" then you're doing something dreadfully wrong! :)

Comment: but this is what my client wants. . i need answer pls

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a SELECT query using [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) function -

```
SELECT LPAD(id, 4, 0) FROM table;
```

the query will show a string like this - `'0001'`.

Comment: ^^, im sorry if my question wasn't clear, what i need is one insert query for all. but each of them had different length for ID. in your example, the length was 4, how about my other table that also use this query with more than 4 in length for char

Comment: Instead of constant, you can reference any column of your tables or use an expression, like: `lpad(id, length(somefield), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 = LPAD(id, 3, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something in your question but instead of tweaking the query, have you considered the ZEROFILL option in your tables structure ?

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`TEST_LEADING_ZERO` (
    `ID` INTEGER UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: unfortunately i cant alter the table, lets say i have $query = insert into {$tbl} values {$array}

Comment: ouh, sorry, now i using $query to insert all of the data, but they have different length for ID like the 1st tbl has (CHAR3) the second one has (CHAR 4), is there a way i can still use one query for them?

Comment: Then Devart's answer might be the best one for you :)

Comment: hmmm, not sure bout that, help me pls guys