# php 5, for loop not displaying correctly series of numbers that starts with 0

Tags: php, for-loop

I'm trying to get the results of the for loop like: `00001, 00002, 00003,` etc. but the result is not displaying `0`'s: instead I get: `1, 2, 3,` etc.

This is the code:

```
$min = 00001;
$max = 00005;

for ($x = $min; $x <= $max; $x++) {
    echo "$x ";
}
```

Comment: you need to use `str_pad`

Comment: Leading zeroes aren't just eliminated; any integer starting with a zero is interpreted as an Octal number. That means that 0010 isn't representing the decimal number 10, but the decimal number 8! Never prepend PHP ints with 0 unless you're working with Octals.

Comment: Actually i will be working with higher values like $max = 0387648

Comment: *"Actually i will be working with higher values like `$max = 0387648`"* - why the leading zero? Again, as Erik states and Rizier's answer below; leading zeros are treated as octals. Have you tried Rizier's answer? @narclax

Comment: I think i will need to work with octals, i need to work with zeros because the application needs to insert the exact serial for some labels to be printed.

Comment: You know you can achieve that in MySQL, having leading zeros as the column's leading character. There are a few ways of doing this, and in PHP also. I've seen it before; it's a tad complex, but that may be what you need to do instead. Using octals might not produce the desired results. Are you 100% sure you want to use octals? @narclax

Comment: No, actually i'm hoping to get some better way to approach this issue. What method can you advise me?

Comment: See the Q&A's here http://stackoverflow.com/q/11165104/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6873354/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/10944167/ @narclax

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Doing the trick via MySQL got everything done. Just had to change the value to decimal and assign the field size (7) with the corresponding zerofill attribute. now i can insert the count of the foorloop without zeros but the db inserts them for me. Thanks Fred!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for the help. Doing the trick via MySQL got everything done. Just had to change the value to decimal and assign the field size (7) with the corresponding zerofill attribute.

Now i can insert the count of the `for` loop without zeros but the db inserts them for me. Thanks

Comment: Ah, so my links/suggestion did help after all, *great!* - Another happy ending ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Just change your echo statement to this:

```
echo sprintf('%05d', $x);
```

Also i would recommend you to change your `$min` and `$max` variables to this:

```
$min = 1;
$max = 5;
```

Because if you have leading zeros then number gets interpreted as an `octal` number! So `00012` would not be `12`  it would be `10`.

Comment: *Because if you have leading zeros then number gets interpreted as an octal number* - ***Exactly.***

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$min = 00001;
$max = 00005;
for ($x = $min; $x <= $max; $x++) {
printf("%5d",$x);
}
?>
```

[image]

this is new code

```
<?php
$min = 00001;
$max = 00005;
for ($x = $min; $x <= $max; $x++) {
printf("%05d",$x);
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what OP wants! Read the question properly...

Comment: you wnat exectly four 0's

Comment: *Because if you have leading zeros then number gets interpreted as an octal*. @vikramsharma which is what will happen with yours also.